# .c file is not recgnized

Tags: c, cmake

I cannot build c project.
I am novice of C language, so I can't understand what is problem.
Webstorm setting, or setting of cmake ?

Why I cannot build my projects.

Environment:

1. Editor: Clion
2. Created Project from C Executable
3. Lnaguage standard: C99

Error message

```
/Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/bin/cmake --build /Users/me/CLionProjects/test/cmake-build-debug --target test -- -j 2
[ 50%] Linking C executable test
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_test", referenced from:
      _main in main.c.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[3]: *** [test] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/test.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/test.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [test] Error 2
```

I wrote main.c

```c
#include "header.h"

int main() {
    test();
    return 0;
}
```

header.h file

```c
void test();
```

header.c file

```c
#include "header.h"

void test() {
}
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(test C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)

add_executable(test main.c)
```

dicrectory structure is like this.

```
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── cmake-build-debug
│   ├── CMakeCache.txt
│   ├── CMakeFiles
│   │   ├── 3.15.3
│   │   │   ├── CMakeCCompiler.cmake
│   │   │   ├── CMakeDetermineCompilerABI_C.bin
│   │   │   ├── CMakeSystem.cmake
│   │   │   └── CompilerIdC
│   │   │       ├── CMakeCCompilerId.c
│   │   │       ├── a.out
│   │   │       └── tmp
│   │   ├── CMakeDirectoryInformation.cmake
│   │   ├── CMakeOutput.log
│   │   ├── CMakeTmp
│   │   ├── Makefile.cmake
│   │   ├── Makefile2
│   │   ├── Progress
│   │   │   ├── 2
│   │   │   └── count.txt
│   │   ├── TargetDirectories.txt
│   │   ├── clion-environment.txt
│   │   ├── clion-log.txt
│   │   ├── cmake.check_cache
│   │   ├── progress.marks
│   │   └── test.dir
│   │       ├── C.includecache
│   │       ├── DependInfo.cmake
│   │       ├── build.make
│   │       ├── cmake_clean.cmake
│   │       ├── depend.internal
│   │       ├── depend.make
│   │       ├── flags.make
│   │       ├── link.txt
│   │       ├── main.c.o
│   │       ├── progress.make
│   │       └── src
│   ├── Makefile
│   ├── cmake_install.cmake
│   └── test.cbp
├── header.c
├── header.h
├── main.c
└── src
```

Comment: Missing `header.c` in `CMakeLists.txt`?

Comment: `header.c` should be along with `main.c` in the add_executable line.

Comment: Thank you, I understand what was problem.
@kaylum

Comment: I understand.
CMakeLists.txt is used to identify which file to include in build context.

@AProgrammer